# I want to get one line as header and rest data is append in file

Tags: java, file, file-handling

I want to get one line as header and then rest of data append in the file.but i am facing issue that it is saving the header repeatedly when i have called the function.

### Expected output should be like

#### Id :  Title  : Group ID

1 :   ab   :   2

2 :  fd   :   3

3 :  fwsj   : 3

```
public void writeOutputToFile(int id, String title, int groupId) throws IOException {

        OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(new File("output_report.txt"), true);
        os.write("\n  Id      Title     Group ID \n ".getBytes());

        os.write((id + "             " +title + "     " + groupId + "\n").getBytes());
        os.close();


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

### The Problem

It is repeatedly putting in the header, because when you call the method, you are always going to insert the header. Instead, you may want to code a util that inputs headers for a file you are creating, and then a separate method for inserting the data.

### The Solution

**Solution 1)**

The helper util method would look something like this:

```
// String... allows for multiple string parameters to be entered for all of your headers.
public void prepFile(File f, String... headers) {
     StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
     for (String header : headers) {
         buffer.append(header + "\t");
     }

     OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(f, true);
     os.write(buffer.toString().getBytes());
     os.close();

}
```

After the file is prepped, you can then use your writeOutputToFile method for all the data.

### Edit

**Solution 2)**

If you were going to make a stand alone class for this, I would recommend you set it up like so:

```
import java.io.*;

public class OutputFile {

    private File file;
    private String[] headers;
    private boolean existed;

    public OutputFile(File f, String... headers) {
        this.file = f;
        this.headers = headers;

        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        existed = file.exists();

        // If the file didn't exist, then you want to create it.
        if (!existed) {
            try {
                file.createNewFile();

                // Afterwards, you can then write your headers to it.
                if (headers != null) {
                    writeData(headers);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public void writeData(int id, String title, int groupId) {
        writeData("" + id, title, "" + groupId);
    }

    public void writeData(String... strings) {
        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
        for (String s : strings) {
            buffer.append(s + "\t");
        }
        buffer.append("\n");

        writeData(buffer.toString());
    }

    public void writeData(String data) {
        OutputStream os = null;
        try {
            os = new FileOutputStream(file, true);
            os.write(data.getBytes());
            os.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (os != null) {
                try {
                    os.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: sir please update your answer as per my method. I am unable to implement this.

Comment: I added an example of how you would build a class around this design.

Answer (score 0):

well, inside your method you write the headers to the file, so obviously whenever you call it they'll get written..

You can separate it to two methods- one that writes the headers (and called only once) and another that writes the data (and called once per row).
Alternatively, use some sort of loop inside your method to write each of the lines to the file, after writing the headers once.